# package.json run 2 git command on 1 script

Tags: npm, package.json

Currently I have thiss script in my `package.json`:

```
"submodule-install": "git submodule add ../my-utils.git modules/my-utils --force",
"submodule-update": "git submodule update --init --force --recursive --remote",
```

I need to add an extra `git` command, plus, I need to use some variable on it.

I need to `git checkout` to some specific branch according some environment defined on an external file, for instance a `.env` file.

Is there a way that I could do that?

My idea is something like:

```
"submodule-install": "git submodule add ../my-utils.git modules/my-utils --force && git checkout $ENV",
"submodule-update": "git submodule update --init --force --recursive --remote && git checkout $ENV",
```

Where `$ENV` be an environment value taken from `.env` file.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Git doesn't know a package.json file from a box.yaml or envelope.csv. What matters here is the program *reading* the package.json file, presumably npm.

Comment: This seems like a somewhat similar scenario to of conditionally running `npm install` for git-test, you can look at https://github.com/mhagger/git-test/blob/master/env.md and the hints about `git submodule`. You could run a javascript file with npx/node instead of a shell script and have it read configuration from a .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use an environment variable from a .env file to determine the branch to checkout in a git command. Here's how you can achieve that:

1. Create a .env file in your project directory and define the environment variable `$ENV` with the desired branch name.
2. Modify your git commands to include the branch checkout using the environment variable. Here's an example:

   - `"submodule-install": "git submodule add ../my-utils.git modules/my-utils --force && git checkout $ENV"`
   - `"submodule-update": "git submodule update --init --force --recursive --remote && git checkout $ENV"`

   In these commands, `$ENV` will be replaced with the value of the environment variable defined in the .env file.
3. Make sure to load the environment variables from the .env file before running the git commands. You can use tools like `dotenv` or `direnv` to automatically load the .env file.

By following these steps, the git commands will checkout the branch specified in the `$ENV` environment variable, allowing you to switch branches dynamically based on the environment defined in the .env file.

Please note that the specific implementation may vary depending on your project setup and the tools you are using. It's recommended to refer to the documentation or community resources of the specific tools you are using for more detailed instructions and examples.

Comment: What about using variables? like I asked